# Issue with price format on Product Page (getPriceHtml)

Tags: javascript, magento, currency, webshop

I'm having troubles with the price formatting on a product page of a downloadable product.
The format (as defined globally) should be EUR 15.23. It work's fine in the sidebars, category pages, homepage and so on.
Anyway, on the product page the price is shown wrong (without space): EUR15.23

catalog/product/view.phtml:

```
//calling once - price EUR15.23
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true); ?>

//calling twice - first price EUR15.23 second price EUR 15.23 (correct)
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true); ?>
```

same problem when calling:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?>
```

I think it has to do with the `reloadPrice : function()` JavaScript Code in 
downloadable/catalog/product/links.phtml

Anyone also had this problem?
Actually I don't want to get through the JavaScript-Code and change something here as I do not want to change the core files.

Thanks!

Comment: What actually is the problem? Is it that you are not getting the space between "EUR" and the number? If you think it has to do with a certain piece of JavaScript Code how about you show us that code? Assuming that is the problem, how do you want to fix it when you say you don't want to change the JS code?

Comment: thanks, i might not have stated clearly what the problem is and added it above. yes, the problem is the missing space on the product pages.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it isn't right solution, but if I got you right and it is always true that "first price EUR15.23 second price EUR 15.23 (correct)", then why not just

```
<?php $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true); // no output  ?> 
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true); // correct output ?>
```

Comment: Nice idea. I tried it but as the problem has to do with the re-formatting of the price via JavaScript, it doesn't help.